# Why we should set arguments in sudoers configuration?

Tags: sudo

Why should we set arguments in sudoers configuration? For example

```
user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/reboot -f ""
```

here I can call only "reboot -f" command. So if I set

```
user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/reboot -f *
```

or

```
user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

How can someone use this to hack or do something?

Comment: Consider `reboot -p`, then  drive three hours to restart the machine.

Comment: Imagine needing to give rights to `service` or `systemctl`. You want to make very sure they can only restart their own service.